# Adding multiple keys to a value in hashMap

Tags: java, html, hashmap, synchronization, bufferedreader

I currently have the following data in HTML form:

```
Year| car type     | # of cars sold
2001| Toyota-Camry | 242435
2000| Honda-Accord | 344423
2001| Honda-Accord | 555255
2000| Honda-Civic  | 342344
2008| Toyota-Prius | 666154
1996| Honda-Accord | 114526
2001| Toyota-Prius | 90234
```

In order to retrieve this data, I have a `BufferedReader` that reads in the lines from HTML. I skip a couple lines in the beginning before the data is present because there are empty spaces. So my code currently is

```
public class carSales {
    private Map<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>> carSalesMan = 
            new HashMap <Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>>;

private void getcarTypes(String url) {
    try {
    URL urlz = new URL(url);
    URLConnection urlc = myURL.openConnection();
    BufferedReader line = new BufferedReader
    (new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

    String next;
    next = line.readLine(); 

    while (next.contains("</s>") {
        String[] parts = next.split(" ");

        if (carSalesMan.isEmpty() || carSalesMan.get(Integer.parseInt(parts[0])) == null {
            carSalesMan.put(Integer.parseInt(parts[0], new HashMap<Integer, String>());
            carSalesMan.get(Integer.parseInt(parts[0])).put(Integer.parseInt(parts[2]), parts[1])

        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

the problem with this is that it seems to only store datas that have unique years. So the size of my `carSalesMan` variable would be 4 because I only have 4 unique years and they overwrite each other as the list goes down. Is there a simple way to add all the car types even if its the same year?

Comment: Yes, a `Map` is a unique mapping of a key to a value. What you should probably do is create an object that has the year, car type, and units sold (don't forget `.equals()` and `.hashcode()`, then place those into a structure (perhaps a Set) and process as needed.

Comment: This doesn't look like a use case for a `Map`. You're doomed to continually nest more and more `Map`s with each addition of a new field. Instead, you should create a `Car` class, and use a `List<Car>` or a `Set<Car>`.

Comment: @4castle yea I understand but unfortunately this is a project requirement for using HashMaps and Maps

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the project requirements actually are, since this could be an XY problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one item because of your if-statement:

```
    if (carSalesMan.isEmpty() || carSalesMan.get(Integer.parseInt(parts[0])) == null {
```

You have two options, if you want to have a different slot for each item, you will need to either take @JacobG. answer or you can remove this if statement and user a map type that stores a collection of items as it's value. You would have two ways to do the second options:

I believe you want a MultiValueMap instead of a HashMap it works almost the exact same as a HashMap, except for it stores the values in a collection for each key instead of just a single value at each key.

It isn't official Java, but it is open source.
You can find the documentation here:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html

Alternatively, you could do implement it yourself using a custom class that extends `HashMap<K, V>` that encapsulates a `HashMap<K, Collecton<V>>`

Comment: couldn't figure out how to tag @jacob-g in my answer

Comment: Don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to achieve here is utilizing two separate keys to store a value.  Using an external library such as Guava, this is equivalent to a `Table<Integer, Integer, String>`.  If you're not looking to use any external libraries, then a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>>` is a perfectly fine object to use in this case.

The problem with your current code is that it's only adding information when the `Map` is either empty or does not contain a specific year.  You can change it to the following and it will work fine:

```
public class carSales {
    private Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> carSalesMan = new HashMap<>();

    private void getcarTypes(String url) {
        try {
            URL urlz = new URL(url);
            URLConnection urlc = urlz.openConnection();

            BufferedReader line = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

            String next = line.readLine(); 

            while (next.contains("</s>") {
                String[] parts = next.split(" ");

                int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                int amountSold = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
                String model = parts[1];

                carSalesMan.putIfAbsent(year, new HashMap<>());
                carSalesMan.get(year).put(amountSold, model);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to close your connections/readers to prevent memory leaks as well!

Edit: If you would like to utilize Guava's `Table` ADT, you can use the following:

```
public class carSales {
    private Table<Integer, Integer, String> carSalesMan = HashBasedTable.create();

    private void getcarTypes(String url) {
        try {
            URL urlz = new URL(url);
            URLConnection urlc = urlz.openConnection();

            BufferedReader line = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

            String next = line.readLine(); 

            while (next.contains("</s>") {
                String[] parts = next.split(" ");

                int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                int amountSold = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
                String model = parts[1];

                carSalesMan.put(year, amountSold, model);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer !! could you elaborate on closing my connections and readers if you could ?

Comment: You're welcome!  And sure.  I'm not sure if you're concerned about how to properly close connections/readers, or why you should close them, so it would be helpful if you could specify that.  If you don't close a connection/reader, then associated system resources will not release.  It's bad practice not to close them, as continuously opening connections will result in a memory leak due to a lack of resources required.

Comment: I was wondering about how you're supposed to close the connection/reader.

Comment: Technically I don't think the `URLConnection` should give you any issues, but you can call `line.close();` after the while loop has terminated.

Comment: is there any difference between using `line.flush()` and `line.close()` ?

Comment: `BufferedReader#flush` flushes the buffer and still allows data to be read, but `BufferedReader#close` flushes and closes the buffer.  If you want to read more data after closing, you'll have to instantiate a new `BufferedReader`.

Comment: This is a good answer to the question as asked, however I think this statement might not be true: "a Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> is a perfectly fine object to use in this case".  I doubt that map lookups by # of cars sold is actually needed, and further, if two models had the same number of sales in a given year then data would be lost.  Unfortunately it is unclear from the question what the lookup needs for the problem are.

Comment: @JacobG. they should really declare your BufferedReader and an Input Stream Reader variables outside of the scope of the try and assign them null. then try to instantiate a them inside of the try. Lastly you need to add a finally block after your catch block, and inside of the finally you should check if each item is not null and if not, close them and then set them to null.

Comment: @TrevorFreeman I agree that the program's structure isn't the best, but I dislike criticizing anyone's intentions.  I'd rather not spend the time to rewrite everything to be as efficient as possible, because most likely it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @MBurnham That was the pre-Java 7 way of doing it, you can simply use a try-with-resources statement now.

Comment: @JacobG. It is not criticizing to ask the problem being solved: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  More importantly, if this is for a homework project then I suspect the test data will have a data set that includes entries with duplicate numbers of sales for different models in the same year

Comment: @TrevorFreeman I'd rather not make assumptions.  If the OP would like a specific use-case to work if it doesn't already, I'll fix up the code.

Comment: I agree with @TrevorFreeman I don't think Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> is a good life choice. It would be far less messy to create a custom class that Implements the map interface and encapsulates the use of that collection as a value

Comment: @MBurnham Implementing the `Map` interface is a bit ridiculous, as you'd need to override numerous methods, most of which won't be used.

Comment: Or maybe just reverse the second map?  It really should be car model to sales instead of sales to model, unless the use case is really strange.  Model per year should be unique, whereas # of sales per model is definitely not guaranteed to be unique so the structure is flawed.

Comment: @JacobG. It really wouldn't be that ridiculous. Alternatively they could Extend HashMap<Integer, String> and encapsulate the collection use that way

Comment: @MBurnham It would, as you'd be required to override 12 different methods.

Comment: @JacobG. This is starting to get off topic, but they would be small method implementations, and it would make the consuming code a lot easier to read and deal with later on

Answer (score 0):

Hi I would investigate deeper in to Java's libraries:

"The Java Collections Framework doesn't include an interface for multimaps because they aren't used all that commonly. It's a fairly simple matter to use a Map whose values are List instances as a multimap."

source : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html